# Sync reminders/todo between android and yosemite

Tags: macos, android, reminder

I currently have a macbook pro running yosemite and a galaxy s6 running android. I'm looking for a solution to somehow sync reminders between my Macbook and phone.

I used to have an iPhone for a little while and the reminders worked like a charm. Now I installed wunderlist but it's not working exactly the way I want it.

For example, I can't say "Remind me to do x **tomorrow**". With Apple reminders it would add a reminder for tomorrow. In wunderlist I have to do that manually, and add to that the separation between due dates and reminders makes it somewhat of a hassle.

To make things 'worse', wunderlist only shows things that are due in the notification center and not my to-do's. Well... it should show them but the widget is always empty.. even when I set due dates to yesterday.

So if anyone knows of a way to keep reminders and their notifications in sync between OSX and Android that would be great.

I prefer free solutions if possible. If all else fails I might just try to develop a bridge between the two reminder services (osx to android)